# Remove line-crossing in Graphviz; layout different in jupyter and webgraphviz

Tags: jupyter-notebook, graphviz, dot

I'm looking for a way to remove an unacceptable line crossing in a simple `dot` script. There is no line-crossing when the code is executed in http://www.webgraphviz.com/, but there is a line-crossing when the exact same code is executed in a Jupyter notebook. I'd be grateful for a suggestion of how to remove the line-crossing in Jupyter, that is, to make the layout in Jupyter look like the layout in webgraphviz.

Here is the `dot` code:

```
Digraph X {
    rankdir=LR;
    {rank=same; a b}
    {rank=same; d c}
    z -> a
    a -> b
    b -> c
    c -> d
    d -> a   
}
```

In http://www.webgraphviz.com/, it displays as follows:

[image]

But, in Jupyter, it displays as follows, with an unacceptable line-crossing:

[image]

The jupyter code is the following:

```
import graphviz
graphviz.Source('''Digraph X {
rankdir=LR;
{rank=same; a b}
{rank=same; d c}
z -> a
a -> b
b -> c
c -> d
d -> a
}''')
```

Answer (score 0):

This took some trial and error and piecing together clues from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html

```
import graphviz
graphviz.Source('''Digraph X {
rankdir=RL;
{rank=sink; z}
{rank=same; c d}
{rank=same; a b}
z -> a
a -> b
b -> c [constraint=false]
c -> d [constraint=false]
d -> a
}''')
```

[image]